# What is the difference between the sphere and projective space?

Tags: coding-theory, projective-geometry, spherical-geometry

I know about the antipodal mapping.

What I want to know is what the most significant differences between the sphere and projective space are, and how to think of each of them and their relationship to one another.

I come at this from a coding theory/vector quantization perspective; I'm trying to understand the difference between quantization techniques that codes a set of vectors in $R^n$ based on their direction vs. based on their *oriented* direction.

Comment: Hi: welcome to math.SE. Please don't pile on tags as haphazardly as you did. Pick tags that describe what is important to the question. Algebraic geometry, differential geometry and machine-learning do not have nearly as much to do with your question as projective-geometry and spherical geometry do.

Comment: Could you say more about "quantization techniques" you are referring to? I've studied a lot of coding theory but I don't know (or don't recognize) what you're talking about. Look forward to seeing the details: regards!

Comment: The scope of what you want is also unclear. You just want to compare the two sets of points? Or are you interested in their geometry as well? Their topology? All of the above?

Comment: Sorry about the tags, I just wasn't sure what to put... I'm not really sure what sort of comparisons I want, I just want to get a good sense of what the significant differences and similarities are... it is deliberately open ended because I want people to give their perspective on what is significant.  

By quantization I mean vector quantization.  Suppose you have a set of vectors and you are going to quantize them either by points of the sphere, or by lines through the origin.... what differences emerge?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "quantize," and none of the hits I get on google seem relevant. It seems to be an unrelated physics term. It sounds like you want to represent the points with some coordinates. Is that close to what you mean?

Comment: I'm talking about this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_quantization

Answer (score 3):

- On the sphere, any two "lines" intersect twice; in the projective plane, just once.
- The sphere is oriented; the projective plane is not.  The letter R has more asymmetry than other letters of the alphabet; move and "R" around the projective plane and keep it going in the same direction until it returns to where it started.  It will be a backwards, mirror-image "R".
- The sphere is simply connected: Draw any curve that returns to its starting point,  and it can be contracted to a point.  A line in the projective plane cannot be so contracted.

Comment: @rschwieb : I've changed it to "lines" with quotation marks.  Why would you say geodesics don't intersect?  Aren't geodesics just great circles?

Comment: In some fields of geometry "geodesic" refers to distance minimizing paths between two points. In that sense, it's easy to construct such pairs of curves that don't intersect, or intersect in only a point. "Line" is just a safer, plainer choice as long as the context of spherical geometry is clear.

Comment: I took "geodesic" to mean a curve that is _locally_ a distance-minimizing path, and that can't be extended to a longer one.  But I don't know what the standard usage is.

Comment: Oh I wouldn't say there's one standard usage. Both usages are pretty common. This suggestion isn't a correction, it's just to hedge our bet on terminology.